# Django + AJAX - POST 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Estou tentando implementar um sistema de likes numa aplicação Django + AJAX mas, ao tentar fazer a operação em questão estou recebendo o seguinte erro no console do navegador: `POST http://localhost:8000/forum/like/ 404 (Not Found)`. Não sei o que está ocorrendo, alguém pode ajudar? Segue partes do meu código abaixo:

### views.py

```
@require_POST 
def toggle_like(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user
        slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug)

        if question.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            question.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            question.likes.add(user)
    
    context = {'likes-count': question.likes.count}

    return HttpResponse(json.dump(context), content_type='application/json')
```

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'forum'

urlpatterns = [
    path('like/', views.toggle_like, name='toggle-like'),
]
```

### question.html

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $('#like').click(() => {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'forum:toggle-like' %}",
                data: {
                    'slug': $(this).attr('name'),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: (response) => {
                    alert(response.message);
                },
                error: (response, error) => {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Likes: {{ question.likes.count }} <input type="button" id="like" name="{{ question.slug }}" value="Like" /></p>
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: tens como postar o traceback do erro e qual a versão do Python e do Django que tu está usando? Só observando o teu código tem alguns pontos onde o erro pode estar acontecendo. **views.py** slug = request.POST.get('slug', None)
question = get_object_or_404(Question, slug=slug) O 404 pode acontecer que o parâmetro 'slug' não está sendo passado corretamente no POST, tenta colocar um print(slug) antes do get_object_or_404. **url.py** E como está o teu arquivo urls.py raiz? O problema pode estar nele. Com mais informações eu posso te ajudar melhor. Abraço

Comment: Com o `DEBUG=True` não sai nada mais indicativo do erro? Poderia aproveitar pra entender como ele tá formatando as URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que seja problema de escopo no JavaScript. Quando você acessa `$(this).attr('name')`, o `$(this)` está se referindo ao método `ajax` e não ao elemento com ID `#like`. Daí o que está acontecendo é que `$(this).attr('name')` está retornando `undefined` ou uma string vazia. Este valor por sua vez está sendo usado como parâmetro na busca `get_object_or_404`, que está retornando `Http404`.

No JavaScript, tente armazenar o botão `#like` em uma variável e então acessa-lo para compor os dados do POST.

```
{% block javascript %}
    <script>
        $('#like').click(() => {
            likeButton = $(this)
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "{% url 'forum:toggle-like' %}",
                data: {
                    'slug': likeButton.attr('name'),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: (response) => {
                    alert(response.message);
                },
                error: (response, error) => {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
{% endblock  %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Likes: {{ question.likes.count }} <input type="button" id="like" name="{{ question.slug }}" value="Like" /></p>
{% endblock  %}
```